# Sharepoint 2013 hide list except for certain users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to restrict access to a custom Sharepoint list but not only in terms of create/view/modify items access but also in terms of its visibility. The list itself (the "tile" in the site contents) should not be visible to anyone except to a group of selected users. Is there a way to acheive this in Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like OOTB functionality for SharePoint.

Users without access to a list will not see it unless the link has been hard-coded in somewhere, and even then if they browse to it they'll be hit with access denied.